# Is there a way to access an iteration-counter in Python's for loop?

Tags: python, foreach

Is there a way to access an iteration-counter in Python's for loop?

I usually use my own variable and increase it in any loop. Is there a more pythonic way?

Comment: There is no counter! Well, inside the iterator there may be, and there's a special case for array-like objects that does count, but generally it's just an iterator object that's asked to provide the next value each time.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Use [`enumerate`](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#enumerate):

```
sequence = [1, 45, 65, 7]
for i, val in enumerate(sequence):
    print i, val
```

Output:

```
0 1
1 45
2 65
3 7
```

Answer (score 3):

Not only can you use the `enumerate` builtin, but it has a little-known optional second parameter, the value to start at:

```
f = open(...)
for linenumber, line in enumerate(f, 1):
    # etc.
```

This way you can give your elements a more natural numbering, rather than getting zero for the first element and having to add 1 someplace.